# How to align the buttons side by side within a column wrapped by a Row in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align two raised buttons and an icon in a line that is side by side in a row ..how should I do that?

I have these three inside a column which is wrapped by a row.

I have tried making Column as Row as a result of which the three comes in a line but then the whole body confined just to be there only.

```
child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[

                  RaisedButton(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    child: Text(
                      'LeaderBoard',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    Icons.home,
                    size: 44.0,
                  ),
                  RaisedButton(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                    textColor: Colors.black,
                    child: Text(
                      'Claim @0',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 20.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
                  ),
                ],
              )),
            ],
```

expected that two buttons placed side by side .

Answer (score 0):

You need to simply remove `Column` inside parent `Row` widget and can directly wrap buttons with `Row`. Here's working example which displays buttons and icon in same row:

```
body: Center(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              textColor: Colors.black,
              child: Text(
                'LeaderBoard',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
            ),
            Icon(
              Icons.home,
              size: 44.0,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
              textColor: Colors.black,
              child: Text(
                'Claim @0',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Above code is rendered in UI as below:

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: yep, this will display them side by side but then my bg image will be confined to that row only rather covering the whole body.

Comment: how to add screenshot any idea?

Comment: You'll need to edit your question, then under `Body` section, you'll see `image` icon, click on it then browse the screenshot you want to add and then click on `add picture`.